# php - need advice for dynamic processing sentiment analysis

Tags: php, dynamic, twitter, processing

[image: My tweet sentiment analiysis]

this is screenshoot for my sentiment analysis task.i wanted some advice from you guys.
This program is built with PHP and running static. The result tweets displayed when all input is processed.
my hope is tweet continued to be produced (continuous), and then result of sentiment mapped to the live line graphic.
1. in your opinion, what the most effective way? 
(I think maybe jquery is the tools.but i havent found a continuous processing jquery/javascript) .
2. do you know the sample/project of dynamic/continuous processing with jquery/javascript ?


Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the data with JSON and then fetch them periodically with jQuery getJSON().

Comment: thx 4 the idea. hi, is there any esample of that?let me to know the implmentation.thanks

Comment: Hey no prob. http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Introduction-to-JSON-and-PHP(or something different to expose your data in Json. Fetch your data by using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/.